# Windows 7 Home Premium Ignoring DNS Suffix seach list

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, dns

I am using Cisco AnyConnect to connect to my work network for a work from home situation.  The connection is fine, however I am having a DNS problem.  My work DNS has various suffixes, but for some reason my Windows 7 computer simply ignores them when I add them to the "Append these DNS suffixes (in order)" option in network connection settings.

An example of my problem is this:

I am try to connect to example.foo

The full DNS entry for this entry is example.foo.bar.employer.com.  This full address resolves perfectly.  However, example.foo is not translating to the full version even though bar.employer.com is in my DNS suffix search list.

I have tried the suggestions in this question: [Windows 7 not appending connection-specific DNS suffix](https://superuser.com/questions/71853/windows-7-not-appending-connection-specific-dns-suffix)

However, when I run gpedit.msc I do not have the options that are described in the answers.  Specifically, I do not have "Allow DNS Suffix Appending to Unqualified Multi-Label Name Queries".  I do have an option called "DNS Suffix Search List", although the description says this is for single-label name resolution.

A quick test shows that Windows is properly doing suffix searches with single-label look ups (example) vs multi-label look ups (example.foo).

Here is the output of my ipconfig /all:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MYCOMPUTER
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : bar.employer.com
                                       employer.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client Virtual Min
iport Adapter for Windows x64
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : REDACTED
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : REDACTED(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : REDACTED(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : REDACTED(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : REDACTED(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
                                       REDACTED
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 318768538
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-E8-A6-10-F4-6D-04-73-84-53
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : REDACTED
                                       REDACTED
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : REDACTED
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : REDACTED
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.222(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : REDACTED
                                       REDACTED
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter employer.com:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : REDACTED(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : REDACTED
                                       REDACTED
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5B0333FC-FD61-4ED0-A137-7EB84DD9170A}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```